# How to convert a std::istream to std::wistream

Tags: c++, unicode, stream, ascii

I have an istream and some code expects a wistream.

I literally want every char of a source stream zero extended to a wchar_t.  I don't care about code pages, I don't care about localization, I simply want to seamlessly pipe this input, what's the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a read buffer to adapt the underlying stream buffer in the `istream` to your `wistream`:

```
class adapting_wistreambuf : public wstreambuf {
  streambuf *parent;
public:
  adapting_istreambuf(streambuf *parent_) : parent(parent_) { }
  int_type underflow() {
    return (int_type)parent->snextc();
  }
};
```

Later:

```
istream &somestream = ...;
adapting_wistreambuf sb(somestream.rdbuf());
wistream wistream(&sb);

// now work with wistream
```

This implements only the bare minimum of streambuf's interface. You could add buffer management code to improve performance if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without writing a *complicated* wrapper* around an `std::wistream` to provide an `std::istream` interface. The difference between the two is the char type used when instantiating these classes from templates, thus making `std::istream` (char_type = `char`) and `std::wistream` (char_type = `wchar_t`) in two different class hierarchies. They only share [std::ios_base](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/) as a common base class, which does not provide something useful for your current problem.

Because of that, the following piece of code will not compile (it tries to replace the internal `std::streambuf` of s2 with s1's one, thus making I/O operations on s2 performing on the data from the file) :

```
std::wifstream     s1 ;
std::istringstream s2 ;

// assuming s1 and s2 are correctly initialized ...

s2.ios::rdbuf(s1.rdbuf()) ;  // will not compile, unfortunately, unless the char type
                             // is the same for the two streams :(
```

I'm not aware of a simple solution, perhaps a [Boost IOStreams Filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html?path=4.1.2.3) can be used (I never tried :( ).

If you're not dealing with binary data, and your stream length isn't too big, try reading all the data to a string and then convert (*zero extend* as you say) into an `std::wistringstream`.

* : *complicated* means that you have *reasonable* knowledge about std::streams. I confess I'm not comfortable with streams.

Comment: I never said It's impossible to do, but I hate digging in the deep details of std::streambuf ... (I edited my post for clarity)

Comment: I think you two were correct, it seems possible but digging in to the internals of the STL stream classes was a nightmare in and of itself.  In the end I changed the code to use a boost function with functors to do the conversions needed.